# Safe / Unsafe pattern in scala

Tags: scala

Hi I have class which does some json extraction and want to do a safe/unsafe version.

Currently I have a class definition like this

```
class Safe {
  def getA: Option[String] = ...
  def getB: Option[Int] = ...

  ... etc ... 
}
```

And then a Unsafe version of that which just delegates to the Safe class:

```
class Unsafe(delegate: Safe) {
  def getA: String = delegate.getA.get
  def getB: Int = delegate.getB.get

  ... etc ... 
}
```

this works but obviously the main problem is that the delegation is maintained by hand, and that if we ever change anything about the `Safe` interface, someone has to manually also make sure that is reflected in the `Unsafe` class as well.

Is there a more idomatic and less manual pattern in scala to do this?

Comment: You could at least define a common interface

    `trait ExtractF[F[_]] {
      def getA: F[String]
      def getB: F[Int]
    }`

and then let `Safe` extend `ExtractF[Option]` and `Unsafe` extend `ExtractF[Id]` where

   `type Id[X] = X`

This would at least give you a warning if you forgot a method or two. Would that help?

Comment: huh yea that helps a lot -- being able to state an interface gets me most of the way there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an implementation of my proposal.

1. Define `Extractor` interface parameterized by a type constructor:

   ```
   trait Extractor[F[_]] { outer =>
     def getA: F[String]
     def getB: F[Int]

     /* insert `transform` here */
   }
   ```
2. Implement a `transform` method once and for all, which takes an arbitrary `F ~> G`:

   ```
     def transform[G[_]](natTrafo: F ~> G): Extractor[G] = 
       new Extractor[G] {
         def getA: G[String] = natTrafo[String](outer.getA)
         def getB: G[Int] = natTrafo[Int](outer.getB)
       }
   ```

   Here, the `F ~> G` is a type of polymorphic functions that can transform any `F[A]` into `G[A]` for arbitrary type `A` (`String`, `Int`, or thousand other types you want to `get` in your extractor):

   ```
   trait ~>[F[_], G[_]] {
     def apply[A](fa: F[A]): G[A]
   }
   ```

   This interface is quite ubiquitous, it's available in Scalaz and Cats (it's called `FunctionK` there), sometimes called "natural transformation".
3. Implement `SafeExtractor`:

   ```
   class SafeExtractor extends Extractor[Option] {
     def getA: Option[String] = None /* do sth. more clever here? */
     def getB: Option[Int] = None
   }
   ```
4. Get `UnsafeExtractor` for free by providing a simple `Option ~> Id` implementation to `transform`:

   ```
   type Id[X] = X

   val safe: Extractor[Option] = new SafeExtractor()
   val unsafe: Extractor[Id] = safe.transform(
     new ~>[Option, Id] {
       def apply[A](x: Option[A]): Id[A] = x.get
     }
   )
   ```

You can now also easily reuse the same `transform` function to convert `Extractor[Future]` to `Extractor[Id]` by `Await`ing results, or `Extractor[Id]` to `Extractor[Try]` by catching all errors etc.

**Full code**

```
import scala.language.higherKinds

trait Extractor[F[_]] { outer =>
  def getA: F[String]
  def getB: F[Int]

  def transform[G[_]](natTrafo: F ~> G): Extractor[G] = 
    new Extractor[G] {
      def getA: G[String] = natTrafo[String](outer.getA)
      def getB: G[Int] = natTrafo[Int](outer.getB)
    }
}

/** A polymorphic function that can transform any
  * `F[A]` into a `G[A]` for all possible `A`.
  */
trait ~>[F[_], G[_]] {
  def apply[A](fa: F[A]): G[A]
}


class SafeExtractor extends Extractor[Option] {
  def getA: Option[String] = None
  def getB: Option[Int] = None
}

type Id[X] = X

val safe: Extractor[Option] = new SafeExtractor()
val unsafe: Extractor[Id] = safe.transform(
  new ~>[Option, Id] {
    def apply[A](x: Option[A]): Id[A] = x.get
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Andrey Tyukin is a good way to address this specific problem, but there is perhaps a bigger design issue.

Your code assumes that the structure of the JSON (as defined in `Safe`) matches the structure of the data in your code (as defined by `Unsafe`). This causes problems when you want to change the structure of the data in your code, or when the JSON format changes, or when you want to import data from a different source (e.g. XML), or when you want to do more complex validation of the data.

So the correct way to handle this is to design the application data structures (your `Unsafe` class) in the way that fits your application. You then provide a JSON-reading library that converts incoming data to that format. This library uses your `Safe` class internally. This can perform any validation/data conditioning that may be required, and can adjust to changes in the JSON format without affecting the rest of the system. Your unit testing framework will make sure that your two classes stay in sync.

This design pattern is an example of [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)

---

Here is some sample code:

In the main application:

```
// Data structure for use by application
case class Unsafe(a: String, b: Int)

// Abstract interface for loading data
trait Loader {
  def load(): Unsafe
}
```

In the data loading library:

```
// JSON implementation of loading interface
object JsonLoader extends Loader {

  protected case class Safe(
    a: Option[String],
    b: Option[Int]
  )

  def load(): Unsafe = {
    val json = rawLibrary.readData() // Load data in JSON format
    val safe: Safe = jsonLibrary.extract[Safe](json)

    // Validate/condition the raw data here
    val a = safe.a.getOrElse("")
    val b = safe.b.getOrElse(0)

    // Return the application data
    Unsafe(a, b)
  }
}
```

The mapping from JSON to application data is hidden inside the `JsonLoader` object. This makes it easier to make sure that they are in sync allows the JSON format to change without affecting the wider code.

Comment: I am having a little trouble grasping exactly what you mean, it might be a bit too abstract for me at the moment, can you provide some examples, especially w/r/t to designing data structures to fit an application part. What do you mean exactly?